# BackboneJS collection Fetch empty result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, jsonp

Using a backbone collection I am trying to fetch JSON from a page. However browsing to this page does give me a JSON, using the collection.fetch does not.

Looking in Firebug I see a:

```
"GET http://survey/api/list_surveys    200 OK    4ms"
```

This text however is in red and the Response tab is empty.

The Model:

```
var SurveyList = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        "sid": "",
        "title": '',
        "surveyUrl": ""
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('MODEL AANGESPROKEN');
    }

});
```

The collection:

```
var Surveys = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: BGGZ.SurveyList,

    url: 'http://survey/api/list_surveys'

});
```

The JSON:

```
[{
    "sid":"12345",
    "surveyls_title":"test 1",
    "survey_url":"http://survey/index.php?newtest=Y&sid=12345"
},
{
    "sid":"54321",
    "surveyls_title":"Test 2",
    "survey_url":"http://survey/index.php?newtest=Y&sid=54321"
}]
```

Does anyone has a solution?
I already tried a parse in the collection, but this didn't help.

Might this has something to do with json with padding?
If so How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you doing cross origin request?

Comment: just a heads up, but your `defaults` don't match the properties that you're receiving. defaults.title & response.surveyls_title

Comment: One `guess` is that you have a MIME TYPE problem. Maybe your back-end is configured by default to accept application/xml and it should be application/json ? (just a guess...) Whats your back-end stack look like? RoR? Node?

Comment: At the back-end I am using PHP which expects a post or a get. It will echo a json encoded array. I don't know what Backbone will ask for, however when I use dataType = "JSON" or "JSONP" it won't change anything.

Comment: @BonifatiusK could you extend the question with the code where you're actually fetching this collection?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution here.
As this is a remote server I am getting the json from I can use JSONP.

In the collection.fetch() Backbone uses jQuery's $.ajax() method to get the data. 
So you can place your $.ajax settings in the fetch:

```
myCollection = new Surveys();
myCollection.fetch({

    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }

});
```

Now this will not work if your API doesn't expect a JSONP.
JSONP will give a callback parameter to your API. So did your API call first looked like this:

```
http://survey/api/list_surveys
```

with JSONP it will now look like this:

```
http://survey/api/list_surveys?callback=jQuery12654876544
```

Your API should not return the standard JSON, because jQuery / backbone is expecting the data in a callback function.

if the JSON first looked like this:

```
{
    "sid":"12345",
    "surveyls_title":"test 1",
    "survey_url":"http://survey/index.php?newtest=Y&sid=12345"
}
```

you must now add the API to this callback function:

```
jQuery12654876544({

    "sid":"12345",
    "surveyls_title":"test 1",
    "survey_url":"http://survey/index.php?newtest=Y&sid=12345"

})
```

Now you're done.